# Delayed_job not logging to production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

On my development environment, whenever I run delayed jobs which the method contains a log, it outputs it to the logs, but this is not the case for production. Example:

```
def save_my_model
  Rails.logger.info "MODEL SAVED!"
  p = Profile.new
  p.save
end
```

I'd see the info log in the development.log but this doesn't show in production. How can I make it output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

Look at this links [google discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/JbsVasnouvg) and [github documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#Cant_figure_out_how_to_start_in_production)

OR simply make delayed_job.rb file in `config/initializers` and add following line of code:

```
Delayed::Worker.logger = Logger.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'dj.log'))
```